# UITableView display number of rows according to device (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 15 items in a plist to use as the table row titles.  When I run the app on an iPhone 7 simulator the display looks like this:

[image]

But when I use the iPhone XR simulator it looks like this:

[image]

(The UITableView fills the entire UIView down to the Preferences button.)
Is there a way to

- not cut off the bottom of a cell?
- fill the screen with as many cells as will fit on a particular device's screen?
- have the table cells extend all the way across the screen from left to right?

Comment: You have problems with your constraints... otherwise it should work fine... can you post your view in design mode?

Comment: yes its constraints issue ... share your constraints

Comment: This is without constraints.  When I add constraints, such as centering either horizontally or vertically in window, or x units left/right/top/bottom of safe areas, the table disappears altogether.

Comment: I just deleted the Derived Data folder and it is now filling the screen properly on both devices!  However, the percentage of the bottom cell that is cut off is different on each device.  How do I set constraints to handle that?

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Comment: This shows how the bottom cell appears differently on the 2 devices and the constraints I used:  
https://imgur.com/a/FUBOdZx

Comment: @swiftlearneer: thank you for the edit (tag) suggestion!

Comment: I have seen table view constraints that are perfect, can you share the screenshots of "Preference" view Constrains? And also check the priority of table view and preference view

Answer (score 0):

I think you have fix the table view height. Please remove the height of table view and set bottom constraints.

Comment: I don't have a table view height constraint.

Comment: See comment above:  This shows how the bottom cell appears differently on the 2 devices and the constraints I used: imgur.com/a/FUBOdZx

Comment: Is there any parent view of tableView?

Comment: Other than a UINavigationController, no, this is the entry point.

Comment: Ok. May be the problem is something else. You can share code, i will check and fix.

Comment: See comment above: This shows how the bottom cell appears differently on the 2 devices and the constraints I used: imgur.com/a/FUBOdZx - everything you need is here.